# How to hide checkbox title using CSS

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the image below, the table contents are so long and the last `td` content is hideous. (Sorry for local language, but trust me, the content is not important.)

[image: the last td is hideous]

What I want is hide checkbox titles using only CSS. It's very hard to not output title 'cause it's rendered automatically by a well-encapsulated module. And I don't want to tamper with it. I was successful to add `hide-title` class to `input` itself as follows:

[image: input has hide-title class]

Is it possible to hide checkbox text only using this advantage?

Following is my html:

```
<td id="result_box__is_duplex--0">
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <div class="checkbox">                                        
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hide-title" id="form_product_classes_0_is_duplex" name="form[product_classes][0][is_duplex]" value="1"> 
                両面印刷可能 <!-- Hide this text with custom class -->
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

and each `td`has an id starting with `result_box__is_duplex`. I believe the template uses `Bootstrap` v3.0. Thank you for paying attention.

Comment: you could add that class to the parent element and set a `font-size: 0`

Comment: All I could was to add `hide-title` class to `input` element. As I said earlier, it's rendered by well-designed module, and it's very hard to modify other than that. I think it's possible to select `label` tag using `:has` selector. But how?

Comment: Nope. About `:has` selector: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: I've already read that article. And I misunderstood that it was possible to select parent tag using `:has` selector. But it was **NOT**. That article is misleading unless you read it carefully. Oops.

Comment: you could try [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector on the td or [attribute starts with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector (if all those tds have ids starting with `result_box__is_duplex--`)

Comment: @Pete I used `td[id^="result_box__is_duplex"] .checkbox label` but it selects nothing. I used this selector in jQuery and it worked! I think it has no effect in `CSS` like `:has` selector. What'd you think?

Comment: Should work with css: https://jsfiddle.net/k62s5x1r/1.  Inspect the label and see if you have other styles overriding

Comment: @Pete Thanks a lot! The selector now works. (I've put css into a wrong file.) What about submitting your answer? I could accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [attribute starts with selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) - `[attr^=value]` to target the `td` you want:

```css
td[id^="result_box__is_duplex"] .checkbox label {
  font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="result_box__is_duplex--0">
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <div class="checkbox">                                        
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hide-title" id="form_product_classes_0_is_duplex" name="form[product_classes][0][is_duplex]" value="1"> 
                両面印刷可能 <!-- Hide this text with custom class -->
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to add the .hide-title to the label element and not the input element?  You can then use this, but it's still quite hacky.

```
.hide-title {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion.
Let's change HTML structure a little bit different.

```
<td id="result_box__is_duplex--0">
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <div class="checkbox">   
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value"/>
            <label id="label_id" for="checkbox_id">Text</label>  
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

then you can apply CSS there the way you expect

```
/***** CSS ******/
label#label_id {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```html
<label style="font-size:0"><input type="checkbox" id="check1">Option 1</label>
```